# How to format text using css so it doesn't break with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

My setup is I have a paragraph element inside of a div element as follows:

```
<div class="c1">
  <p class="c2">
    Text dsfjlkdjf kljds flkdsj flkdjf slkdf
  </p>
</div>
```

I've applied some css properties to it which force the text onto 1 line using white-space nowrap and text-overflow: ellipsis.

The issue is when the final word to show is too long, then a few of the characters are shown with the ellipsis e.g. 'abcd...' is there a way to prevent this? I've tried to apply various properties such as word-wrap, overflow-wrap etc but no luck.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want ellipsis? If that's the case, then why did you set `text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

Comment: add your css so far

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I want to use ellipsis for the look it provides but only at the end of whole words.

Comment: @RachelGallen I don't have the css to hand but it's something like this:

white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: So you want the text to be truncated, but only at the end of a word, not in the middle of a word. If the entire text is a single word what do you expect? A blank area?

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to prevent part of a word being cut off with ` text-overflow: ellipsis;`. It just cuts off the text wherever the width of the container ends. You can probably do it with javascript.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger In theory the entire text will never be one word but that is the behaviour I'm expecting for a paragraph of many words.

Comment: @WizardCoder any advice on what to try if I'd like to do this with javascript?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: @jobe Sorry it would involve some work and I just help to fix other peoples existing code. Do some googling and have a go at doing it yourself. If you hit a problem then post another question. P.S. People tend to downvote questions when reproducible code it not provided.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question very well, but try this:

```
.c2{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 75ch; //this unit catch the max character in width 
}
```